# Changing leaderboard features of Swarm Connect

Tags: java, android, leaderboard

Right now the below is what my leaderboard looks like.

[image]

I have 2 questions:

1. How does the user set their name?  "pub_6997" was automatically selected for me when I logged in with Facebook.  I went searching through the settings while playing the app but could not find anything useful.
2. Is there a way to add another column to the leaderboard?  For example a column that are Strings that do not affect the order of the rankings in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lead Developer of Swarm here.

1) A bit ago, we changed from having a split between our publisher accounts and our user accounts.  Many developers already had both accounts (pub/user) and were merged.  Publishers that didn't have a user account were automatically given one, which is what you're seeing there.  Email us (admin@swarmconnect.com) and let us know what username you'd like, and we can manually switch it for you :)

2) We don't currently support display strings in the leaderboards, sorry.

Comment: Perfect answer!  I have also emailed you at the address you provided.  :)